# FabricJS Image clipTo Behaves Very Strangely

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to add an image to the canvas and use clipTo to contain the image inside a container so that when you drag and resize the image it's clipped into a box.

So say the canvas is 1000px x 1000px and the image is positioned at 50,50 and is 900px x 900px that would sit the image in the middle of the canvas. That's all fine.

Then, we add clipTo to the image with exactly the same dimensions and position and would have expected the clip box to actually sit where we tell it to and be the correct size so that the full image is visible until it's scaled or dragged and then gets clipped where the clipTop rect is set... but this isn't the case, the clip itself always ends up smaller than the image even though we have set the dimensions on the image and clip exactly the same, the clip rect also ends up being positioned completely wrong.

Fabric Version: 1.7.16 - we need this version for other things.

Here is a demonstration of what we want and what's actually happening. Don't know if I am misunderstanding how the clip works or if this is a bug.

First image is what we would expect to see, the pug image with the clip rect exactly the same size and position so you can't see it, then you would drag the image around and it would vanish under the clip. The second image is what's actually happening, the clip is the completely wrong size to what the code says??

[image]

[image]

Marked the clip with red so you can see what it's doing.

here is the code just for this example:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainc',{
                width:1000,
                height:1000
            });


            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){


                var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img,{
                    width:900,
                    height:900,
                    top:50,
                    left:50,
                    originX:'left',
                    originY:'top',

                });

                canvas.add(imgInstance);

                imgInstance.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

                    ctx.rect(50,50,900,900);
                    ctx.fillStyle='red';
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.restore();
                };
                canvas.renderAll();

            }
            img.src = 'http://example.com/test/pug.png';
```

EDIT:

Added to JS fiddle but changed the fabric version to 1.7.15 and it works there, but if I use that version of fabric on my local version it still doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/54670/

So what is different on js fiddle?

**EDIT 2:**

Ok so this is driving me nuts, the exact same code works fine on js fiddle but not locally, locally it's still rendering the clip rectangle the wrong size and position: - first image is js fiddle and second is locally with the same code.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Only happens on retina screens

Comment: Fiddle would be better to see your issue!

Comment: I don't really know how to use fiddle, I tried, I included the url for fabric but the code didn't do anything, no canvas showed up

Comment: It was working fine for me. try in other browsers :)

Comment: @NightRyder  Added to JS fiddle but changed the fabric version to 1.7.15 and it works there, but if I use that version of fabric on my local version it still doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/54670/

So what is different on js fiddle? Baring in mind the code is exactly the same on fiddle as my local one.

Comment: try this url instead: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js

Comment: that's still the same it doesn't work on my local version but it works on jsfiddle. - I even took the source from jdfiffle on /show and that doesn't work locally either. This makes no sense! Why does it do what I want when it's on jsfiddle but anywhere else it just produces the same issue with the clip being the wrong size and position?

Comment: @NightRyder updated my question, you can see from those screenshots that something weird is going on. Works fine on jsfiddle but not locally...??? WHAT?

Comment: @NightRyder Ok, so it seems to be something to do with the window size of the browser, if it's not >= to the size of the image this thing happens with the clip. That's a bit stupid, do you know any way of stopping that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168309/discussion-between-night-ryder-and-glen-elkins).

Comment: @NightRyder this only happens on retina